# MongoDB parameters to filter through array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, query-string, builder.io

I have a problem through an array with mongoDB parameters... assuming I have this two arrays

```
const diversityArray = ['video', 'gps']
```

```
const entries = [
  {
    name: 'First entry',
    slug: 'first',
    diversity: 'image, video'
  },
  {
    name: 'Second entry',
    slug: 'second',
    diversity: 'image, gps'
  },
  {
    name: 'Third entry',
    slug: 'third',
    diversity: 'iframe'
  }];
```

How could I do this but with mongoDB parameters? I want to filter all the items in the array that contains one or more of the items on the diversityArray.

```
const filtered = entries.filter(item => diversityArray.some(data => item.diversity.includes(data)));
```

I need to do this because I have a larger and more complex array coming from Builder.io Headless CMS and I want to do the filter in the query.

I have this code right now:

```
    const sets = await builder.getAll('open-dataset', {
      options: { noTargeting: true },
      limit: 100,
      query: {
        data: {
          date: { $gt: newMinYear, $lt: newMaxYear },
          title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' },
          diversity: ...what I want to do
        }
      }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J9MkxtF8T47) what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @ray, thanks for answering. Sort of.. I would like to do something like ```diversity: { $in: diversityArray }```... but considering that diversity can have more than one item (eg: 'video, image'), I would need to check if any of those items are in the diversityArray.

Comment: The solution is currently comparing the setIntersection of diversity and diversityArray? Isn't that what you are looking for? Can you update your question to include expected output for different cases for more elaboration?

Comment: @EmilianoYaryura I think ray's example satisfy your needs. You just need to replace `["video", "gps"]` string literal in the query with your `diversityArray` variable.

Comment: Thanks @user14967413 ! Sorry for this, but it's my first time using mongoDB query operators and it's so difficult. How could I implement that in the 'const sets' i'm doing? because the aggregate doesn't work. Sorry again and thank you so much

Comment: @EmilianoYaryura What type of library do you use? `builder.getAll()` seems unusual for me.

Comment: @user14967413 builder.io is a headless cms (https://www.builder.io/).

Comment: @EmilianoYaryura It looks like `builder.getAll()` method permits only simple queries in `query` field. You need to run aggregation pipeline, equivalent of `db.collection.aggregate()` in `mongosh`.

Comment: @user14967413 I see... and could I do something like 'diversity: { $regex: diversityArray.join(' '), $options: 'i' },' ?? but doing this I'm avoiding fetching the ones that contains one but not all of the diversityArray items... but maybe a workaround to do it? thanks